# Propagate the orientation setup at iTextSharp.text.Document creation to the Print dialog

Tags: c#, .net, itext, httphandler

I use iTextSharp to create a PDF document in Landscape orientation by employing **PageSize.A4.Rotate()** to set its PageSize. The document is fed into a **Stream** and later saved into the database as a byte array (in a VARBINARY field).

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(); 
iTextSharp document = new Document();
document.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());

var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream)
document.Open()

// Write to the document

document.Close();
byte[] file = stream.ToArray();

/* In the actual environment the byte array is stored in the database, to be retrievable later */   

// WHERE context: HttpContext in a class that implements IHttpHandler
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Test.pdf");
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
context.Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf;

context.Response.BinaryWrite(file);
```

The problem I run into is that when its retrieved and opened via a browser (or saved to disk), when printing, the Print dialog opens in the default Portrait orientation.

Since its not the easiest thing to communicate to all users that they should first go to Page Setup and set the orientation to Landscape, how possible is it to propagate the orientation setup used at document creation all the way to the Print dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try setting the `PICKTRAYBYPDFSIZE` property of your `PdfWriter` property to true. Newer versions of Adobe Acrobat/Reader will detect this and automatically check the "Choose paper source by PDF page size" checkbox on the print dialog. Unfortunately this is one of those "hints" that not all PDF readers implement.

```
        string outputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Landscape.pdf");

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER.Rotate()))
            {
                using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
                {
                    writer.AddViewerPreference(PdfName.PICKTRAYBYPDFSIZE, PdfBoolean.PDFTRUE);
                    doc.Open();

                    doc.Add(new Paragraph("test"));

                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Adobe Reader X seems to understand the property. Great intervention! Thanks.

Comment: Before I accept the answer, I want to pin down some inconsistent behavior in the created document. Even without the property you suggested, the Print dialog on a few occassions seems to pick Landscape orientation automatically. Most of the times it doesn't :) One minute "Copy" fails with an error message while another minute it works just fine. To understand everything properly, I decided to introduce different features gradually. Starting with `Phrase`s, `Paragraph`s, `PdfPTable`s, `Image`s, etc - just that I cover all grounds that could be causing this and other problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, PageSize.A4.Height, PageSize.A4.Width, 0);
var document = new Document(rect, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Am not sure about your version of iTextSharp but I dont think `iTextSharp.text.Rectangle` has a constructor that takes 5 parameters. Anyhow, even after removing the fifth parameter (0) after `PageSize.A4.Width` it doesn't work

Comment: I am using the last version from the [itextpdf.com](http://itextpdf.com/download.php).