# Force to print in legal paper

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to generate PDF documents in my asp.net application. That works great. The only issue I have is when I generate a PDF document with size of a legal paper and print it, the printer use the default paper which is letter size. I have to change the printing options manually in order to print it in legal paper. Is there a way I can specify in which paper size I want the document to print programmatically so that I won't have to do it manually?

I'm using this line of code to specify the page size in iTextSharp:

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LEGAL.Rotate());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer in another post: [Propagate the orientation setup at iTextSharp.text.Document creation to the Print dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090806/propagate-the-orientation-setup-at-itextsharp-text-document-creation-to-the-prin).

The key is to set the viewer preference **Choose paper source by PDF page size** to true.

```
writer.AddViewerPreference(PdfName.PICKTRAYBYPDFSIZE, PdfBoolean.PDFTRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control the client printer. That would be a huge security problem in the PDF format. It is up to that computer's settings.

Comment: I don't want to control the client printer, I just want the document to print as is displayed. Other PDF document print in legal paper by default and I want to do exactly that.